# InelliJ IDEA create tests for all functions in file

Tags: intellij-idea

When I press <kbd>⌘⇧T</kbd> in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 it opens up a window that allows me to create tests for all the functions in the current file. Unfortunately I need to click all the checkboxes of all the tests I want to create manually. Is there a way to select them all? <kbd>⌘A</kbd> allows me to select all checkboxes, but there is no way to check them all at once.

[image]

EDIT:

Whenever I press <kbd>⌘A</kbd> and then press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> only the first checkbox will be toggled:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key is supposed to work to toggle all the selected checkboxes.

I've submitted [a bug in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43692).

Comment: If I press `⌘+A` and then press `Spacebar` it only toggles the first checkbox. Might be a bug for my current version.